# How powermockito intercept new instance?

Tags: mockito, classloader, powermockito

I have two classes to try to figure out how `whenNew` works.

```
public class RockService {
    public RockData serv() {
        RockData rockData = new RockData();
        rockData.setName("RockService");
        rockData.setContent("content from rock service");
        return rockData;
    } }
```

And

```
public class RockData {
    String name;
    long id;
    String content;
    // get set method ignored
}
```

With test code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(RockService.class)
public class MockNewInstanceCreation {

    @Test
    public void mockCreationTest() throws Exception {
        RockData rockData = mock(RockData.class);

        when(rockData.getName()).thenReturn("this is mock");

        whenNew(RockData.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(rockData);

        RockService rockService = new RockService();

        RockData servData = rockService.serv();
        System.out.println(servData.getName());
        System.out.println(servData.getContent());
    }
}
```

So at runtime, if not mock, the output `(RockData's getName())` would be "RockService". But with mock, it returns "this is mock". The code works but still I didn't know how exactly Powermock/Mockito did this.

I debugged the code. What confused me is after `RockData rockData = new RockData();` executed, what actually created is exactly the instance that created by `RockData rockData = mock(RockData.class);`. Which means `new RockData()` doesn't create an new instance at all. It just returned an instance that already created. And when debugging, it jumped to `MockGateway.newInstanceCall`.

So how does Powermockito intercept new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerMockRunner runs tests using special class loader - *org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader*.

Instead of loading real class it loads a new one with the same signature. It means that the real constructor won't be invoked.

So the object that is returned by new operator is not a Mock. It is a instance of a different class that could be assigned to the real one and it returns mocked values.

See the code below:

```
public class RockService {

    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    System.out.println("Real construct");
    //Different class loader
    System.out.println(classLoader);
    //The same class
    System.out.println(this.getClass());
}

public RockData serv() {

    RockData rockData = new RockData();

    Class<? extends RockData> clazz = rockData.getClass();
    //This is a different class 
    System.out.println("Mocked class: " + clazz.getCanonicalName());
    //And different classloader
    ClassLoader classLoader = clazz.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println(classLoader);
    //Mocked class instance could be assigned to real one
    System.out.println(RockData.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz));

    //it's instance of both RockData.class and mocked class
    System.out.println(clazz.isInstance(rockData));
    System.out.println(RockData.class.isInstance(rockData));

    rockData.setName("RockService");
    rockData.setContent("content from rock service");
    return rockData;
}
```

Comment: I can get the class loader part. Mock framework will use bytecode gen and class loader to mock the target class. In my case, it is RockData. What confused me is the code where created the instance. Here in my case is RockService. In RockService.serv, "RockData rockData = new RockData();" will create a new instance. How could it be the same instance as "RockData rockData = mock(RockData.class);"? Does Mockito hacked into "new" operation? And return an existing instance instead of creating one? Like String.intern()? Or mockito also modify the bytecode of RockService?

Comment: As it is needed to add @PrepareForTest(RockService.class) to make the case run, not @PrepareForTest(RockData.class). So what does @PrepareForTest for?

Comment: PowerMockito does not modify the bytecode of RockService.  @PrepareForTest(RockService.class) tells Mockito that it must use "hacked" class loader inside RockService class. Without this annotation, it will use standard java class loader so it won't be able to return mock of RockData. whenNew(RockData.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(rockData);  tells Mockito to prepare special classloader and PrepareForTest annotation tells where should it use that,